# threads or multiple process?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

is it more efficient to run multiple instances of a ruby script ? or multiple threads within that single script ?

take for example, a ruby script to check all links of a given domain are working.

would you run multiple instance of this script or multiple threads ?

how do you create multiple threads ?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29114290/do-threads-in-ruby-improve-concurrency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Efficiency" could mean many things. For Ruby < 1.9, the [green threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads) mean that you won't get as much concurrency as you might think out of threads, so using multiple script instances would be the best way to minimize total real time from start to finish.

As to creating them, here is t[he Pickaxe book](http://pragprog.com/book/ruby/programming-ruby) example of downloading pages "in parallel":

```
require 'net/http'


pages = %w( www.rubycentral.com
            www.awl.com
            www.pragmaticprogrammer.com
           )


threads = []


for page in pages
  threads << Thread.new(page) { |myPage|


    h = Net::HTTP.new(myPage, 80)
    puts "Fetching: #{myPage}"
    resp, data = h.get('/', nil )
    puts "Got #{myPage}:  #{resp.message}"
  }
end


threads.each { |aThread|  aThread.join }
```

Comment: It waits until the threads are finished, so (a) you can safely use the results, and (b) you don't want to exit if you have threads doing something important. (They go poof at kernel#exit.)

Comment: Even with native threads in YARV 1.9, you're still stuck with a global interpreter lock, which means that all you get is concurrency, but no parallelism.

Another alternative to threads and manual separate processes is using `fork`, if your system supports that.